# View socket data header?

Tags: c, sockets, network-programming, data-stream

After accepting data from a socket, can I view the header for the data? I want to know what IP address the packet was sent to as I am listening on multiple interfaces.

Comment: Are you talking about TCP, UDP or something else?

Comment: What opperating system are you using?

Comment: For UDP, asked a few times before:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5281409/get-destination-address-of-a-received-udp-packet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`getsockname`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getsockname.html) to fetch the local IP address of the socket.

```
int getsockname(int socket, struct sockaddr *restrict address,
       socklen_t *restrict address_len);
```

Here is an example:

```
struct sockaddr_in addr;
socklen_t len = sizeof(addr);
memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));

getsockname(s, &addr, &len);
```