# getting multicast source IP address on Linux

Tags: linux, networking, network-programming, multicast

I'm using at struct sockaddr_in to receive multicast data sent out from another machine. When I print out the source address using inet_ntop it gives me the source address of the PC that sent the data.

I would like to know if there is a way of getting the multicast address that the data was 'sent to'?

Comment: Look at the destination address field and use inet_ntop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `setsockopt(2)` to set the `IP_PKTINFO` option (see `ip(7)`) on your receiving socket.  Then use `recvmsg(2)` to collect incoming datagrams, with the `msg_control` and `msg_controllen` fields of its `msg` argument referring to a buffer where the datagram's destination address can be captured.

Systems other than Linux might provide this capability through the BSD `IP_RECVDSTADDR` option instead.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5281409/get-destination-address-of-a-received-udp-packet