# UDP server socket IP assignment

Tags: c, linux, sockets, posix

I run the server code below to open a UDP socket. I have two network interfaces on my linux machine and two interfaces are connected to two different networks. I would like the program to listen a specified network (by assigning IP address), therefore I assign an IP address on the UDP socket.

If I use `servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);` the server is able to receive the broadcast and unicast messages. However, if I define the `servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr =inet_addr("10.0.0.6");`then the server can receive the messages originated to `10.0.0.6` but cannot receive the broadcast `10.0.0.255` message (the netmask is **/24**).
[here](http://pastebin.com/9GYbaKRf) is the code that broadcasts the message, and the unicast code is [here](http://pastebin.com/wHgLFAyJ).

Am I assigning the IP address wrong or is the broadcast code wrong?

Server code is:

```
#define BUFSIZE 512
char *SERVER_IP = "10.0.0.6";

int main() {
    int error_count=0, r=0, n=0;
    int sockfd = 0;
    struct sockaddr_in servaddr, cliaddr ,a ;
    socklen_t len; //integer type of width of at least 32 bits
    char mesg[1000];

    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0); // for datagram
    while(sockfd < 0){ //error handling for socket opening
        usleep(500000);
        if (++error_count == 20){//10 times itteration
             fprintf(stderr, "errno:%s - socket opening error - line 223\n ", strerror(errno));
            exit(1);
        }
         sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    }
error_count = 0;

    memset(&servaddr, 0, sizeof(servaddr));
    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servaddr.sin_port = htons(33333); //server listens on this port


   // servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
     servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr =inet_addr(SERVER_IP);
    printf("servaddr.sin_addr:%lu\n",servaddr.sin_addr );
    printf("a.sin_addr:%lu\n",a.sin_addr );

    r = bind(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *) &servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
    while(r < 0){ //error handling for socket binding
        usleep(500000);
        if (++error_count == 20){//10 times itteration
             fprintf(stderr, "errno:%s - socket binding error - line 239\n ", strerror(errno));
            exit(1);
        }
          r = bind(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *) &servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
    }
error_count = 0;


    while(1){
       len = sizeof(cliaddr);
    next:
printf("server is listening\n");
       n = recvfrom(sockfd, mesg, 1000, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &cliaddr, &len);
printf("line195: packet is received: %s\n", mesg);
       if(n < 0){
           fprintf(stderr, "recvfrom error occured - line254\n");
           n = 0;
           goto next;
       }
}
  return 0;
}
```

here is my `ifconfig -a wlan8`

```
wlan8     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 64:70:02:18:1f:b6  
          inet addr:10.0.0.6  Bcast:10.0.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::6670:2ff:fe18:1fb6/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:206 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:297 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:37857 (37.8 KB)  TX bytes:54526 (54.5 KB)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **can** get your server to work as you need with `INADDR_ANY` and proper call to [`setsockopt`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/setsockopt).

It should be something like this, just after the socket creation:

```
memset(&ifr, 0, sizeof(ifr));
snprintf(ifr.ifr_name, sizeof(ifr.ifr_name), "wlan8");
if (setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BINDTODEVICE,
            (void *)&ifr, sizeof(ifr)) < 0) {
     fprintf(stderr, "error at setsockopt, ensure it is running as root.\n");
     exit(1);
}
```

Obviously, you have also to `#include <net/if.h>` and define  `struct ifreq ifr;` at the beginning of `main`.

This way your server will recieve every datagram that targets any of the address of the `wlan8` interface (both broadcast and unicast), but it will ignore other interfaces.

`SO_BINDTODEVICE` has been introduced to linux for DHCP client and server, but requires root permission. You can use [`sudo`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/sudo) or execute the following command from root to set SUID (thus you have control the program execution via group associations)

```
chmod 4750 server_name
```

Obviously you should be careful with such kind of programs, or you will open security a hole in your system.

Finally I suggest you to read

- [Unicast UDP Usage Guidelines for Application Designers](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5405)
- [Chapter 13 from Linux Socket Programming by Example by Warren Gay](http://alas.matf.bg.ac.rs/manuals/lspe/cnode=111.html) (an old but still valuable resource)

Comment: Thank you Giacomo, I have one more question, is `snprintf` necessary there? would it be fine to use `memcpy` instead of `snprintf`

Comment: I prefer snprintf to avoid issues related to null termination. You can use memcpy, but you have to handle the null termination manually.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't doing anything wrong. Linux won't receive broadcast datagrams unless the socket is bound to the broadcast address or INADDR_ANY. You'll need to bind one socket to the unicast address and another socket to the broadcast address, or you can use IP_PKTINFO to find the destination address if you bind to INADDR_ANY. There is some example code over at [Get destination address of a received UDP packet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5281409/get-destination-address-of-a-received-udp-packet).

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to listen to interface `wlan8` only, try with listening to the entire network - `10.0.0.0` in this case. If you bind to the IP of the interface it probably will receive only messages with it as destination.

Comment: I replaced char `char *SERVER_IP = "10.0.0.6";` with `char *SERVER_IP = "10.0.0.0";` but it still does not receive the broadcast packet and unicast packet as well.