# Receiving UDP broadcasts on machine with two Etherent ports

Tags: c, sockets

A machine has two Ethernet ports and is connected to network using both of them (for redundancy). Another machine periodically sends UDP broadcasts all over the network.

I need to detect through which Ethernet port did I receive the broadcast. I need to know this because, in case of one Ethernet port (line) failure, I need to mark the invalid port.

At the moment I am using recvfrom() socket function to receive UDP broadcasts, but I don't know how to tell through which Ethernet port was the UDP packet actually received.

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get destination address of a received UDP packet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5281409/get-destination-address-of-a-received-udp-packet)

Comment: Maybe it's better to use some kind of link aggregation if your hardware supports it e.g. LACP (IEEE 802.3ad Link Aggregation Control Protocol (LACP)): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_aggregation#Link_Aggregation_Control_Protocol

Answer (score 3):

I've never done this in plain C but you should be able to bind your socket to a specific adapter before calling recvfrom, so you'll have two UDP listeners here - one for each adapter.