# unicast, multicast, broadcast packet

Tags: windows, driver, ndis

I am developing a NDIS driver. NDIS sends packet to miniport. How will I know that the packet comes from NDIS is unicast, multicast or broadcast packet.How to find out a packet is unicast, multicast or broadcast..

Comment: Perhaps you could [Get the destination address from the packet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5281409/get-destination-address-of-a-received-udp-packet) and work it out from there.

Comment: Once I get the destination address then how can I identify that it is unicast, multicast or broadcast packet..

Comment: Unicast, multicast and broadcast addresses have different characteristics.  Check out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast_address

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are writing an Ethernet driver (or at least, your media is similar to IEEE 802's MAC) you can use the `ETH_IS_BROADCAST` and `ETH_IS_MULTICAST` macros from ndis.h.  Anything not broadcast or multicast is unicast.

For a code sample, see [`NICGetFrameTypeFromDestination`](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/NDIS-Virtual-Miniport-58d27f0f/sourcecode?fileId=51285&pathId=108856790) from [the netvmini sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/NDIS-Virtual-Miniport-58d27f0f).