# Linux UDP server - Destination IP wrong

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, networking, udp

I have a embedded linux device that listens for UDP packets. 
The device has two ethernet interfaces so the packets can be retrieved on both interfaces.
On certain UDP messages/packets I have to do do something specific for the interface that it was received on. So I need to detect which interface received the packet.

I have found posts and examples on Stackoverflow showing how to extract the destination IP from `IP_PKTINFO`. This works fine if I test the interfaces one by one. With both interfaces connected and receiving the destination IP is the same.

I have noticed that the    `ifindex` is not the same, but I don't understand why the `ipi_spec_dst` is the same when I clearly receive a packet on two different interfaces with two different IPs.

C/C++ Code responsible for extracting the destination IP:

```
    ssize_t byteCount=recvmsg(f_socket, &message, 0);
    if (byteCount==-1) {
        printf("%s",strerror(errno));
    }

    for (struct cmsghdr *cmsg = CMSG_FIRSTHDR(&message); 
         cmsg != NULL; 
         cmsg = CMSG_NXTHDR(&message, cmsg)) 
    {
        if (cmsg->cmsg_level != IPPROTO_IP || cmsg->cmsg_type != IP_PKTINFO) continue;
        struct in_pktinfo *pi = (struct in_pktinfo*) CMSG_DATA(cmsg);
        char* destAddr = (char*) calloc(4, sizeof(char));
        destAddr = inet_ntoa(pi->ipi_spec_dst);
        std::cout << destAddr << " " << std::to_string(pi->ipi_ifindex) << std::endl;
    }
```

Output eth0 connected:

```
172.20.55.9 4
172.20.55.9 4
172.20.55.9 4
...
```

Output eth0 connected:

```
200.0.0.101 6
200.0.0.101 6
200.0.0.101 6
...
```

Output eth0 and eth1 connected:

```
172.20.55.9 6
172.20.55.9 4
172.20.55.9 6
172.20.55.9 4
...
```

Expected output:

```
200.0.0.101 6
172.20.55.9 4
200.0.0.101 6
172.20.55.9 4
...
```

First of all, I'm not sure if this is expected or not, I do not think it is, but I might have not understood the documentation correctly.

I can supply more code if needed.

Code taken from:

1. [Getting the destination address of UDP packet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31101047/getting-the-destination-address-of-udp-packet)
2. [Get destination address of a received UDP packet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5281409/get-destination-address-of-a-received-udp-packet?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Any and all help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

-aln

Comment: That's **obviously** not C, but C++. There is no language C/C++, only the two **different** questions C and C++.

Comment: How is this obviously not C? Because it contains one line of C++ code? Genuinely interested.

Comment: Because you can't/don't compile it with a C compiler. Read the standards, identical syntax does not imply identical semantics!

Comment: Ok, thank you. I will remember that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by using `ifindex` to get the interface name which I then used to execute the interface specific code.

Answer (score 1):

I Think there is a problem in the lines:

```
char* destAddr = (char*) calloc(4, sizeof(char));
destAddr = inet_ntoa(pi->ipi_spec_dst);
std::cout << destAddr << " " << std::to_string(pi->ipi_ifindex) << std::endl;
```

Two problems:

- You should use `ipi_addr` instead of `ipi_spec_dst` (see [man 7 ip](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/ip.7.html))
- You do not need the calloc stuff (which is

  - not big enough,
  - not correctly initialized,
  - not freed.)

You could simplify it by :

```
printf("%s %d\n", inet_ntoa(pi->ipi_addr), pi->ipi_ifindex);
```

Thus, to resume, your loop could look like:

```
for (   struct cmsghdr *cmsg = CMSG_FIRSTHDR(&message); 
        cmsg != NULL; 
        cmsg = CMSG_NXTHDR(&message, cmsg)) 
{
    if (cmsg->cmsg_level != IPPROTO_IP || cmsg->cmsg_type != IP_PKTINFO) 
        continue;

    struct in_pktinfo *pi = (struct in_pktinfo*) CMSG_DATA(cmsg);
    printf("%s %d\n", inet_ntoa(pi->ipi_addr), pi->ipi_ifindex);
}
```

Comment: ipi_addr returns "255.255.255.255", which is right, because its a broadcast message and not a direct one. Either way thank you for clearing up the calloc thing, it was just a copy paste and I'm new to c/c++.

Comment: @AndréNicolaysen Ok, so in that case, you could use `recvfrom` and use the two last parameters?

Comment: `recvfrom` gives me the `src_addr` which is the address where the packet came from. `pi->ipi_spec_dest` is supposed to give me the local address which the packet was received on. Which it does, but it is wrong if I connect both my interfaces at the same time.

Comment: It seems that what you want to do is difficult: https://stackoverflow.com/q/25070649/1212012

Comment: It seems so. Thank you for finding it. I will have to try some of that stuff out. This is a weird issue, because the `ifindex` is correct every time.

Comment: @AndréNicolaysen: Use `ifindex`.  It exactly meets your requirement "I need to detect which interface received the packet."

Comment: @BenVoigt Looks like it's the easiest solution at the moment, I will update my post tomorrow.