# How to know target address and port when receiving a UDP packet with libuv?

Tags: c++, c, network-programming, udp, libuv

`uvlib` UDP accepts event callback function of the following type:

```
typedef void (*uv_udp_recv_cb)(uv_udp_t* handle,
                               ssize_t nread,
                               const uv_buf_t* buf,
                               const struct sockaddr* addr,
                               unsigned flags);
```

There is no info about target port and address like `sent_to_addr`. Is there way to achieve it?

*I need this to know on what interface packet received, or to know multicast group. Socket listens on 0.0.0.0:xxxx*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, @Inaki right. I found [issues](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/1649) in `node.js` repository. They are active for years. This feature request is still unresolved because of portability problems.

### There are workarounds:

1. for `multicast` -> bind to multicast address.
2. for `unicast` -> bind to concrete local interface, 1 interface - 1 socket. *But keep in mind going this way **dynamic addresses** could become pitfalls*

Answer (score 2):

[IP_PKTINFO](https://linux.die.net/man/7/ip) has such a information, but libuv does not expose an API that enables it.

Answer (score 0):

A quick search shows a similar question:
[Get destination address of a received UDP packet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5281409/get-destination-address-of-a-received-udp-packet)
You can directly invoke system's API to get the info, don't need to bind to the specific address.

Comment: I have read that. Going around `libuv` violates portability! But in particular case it could be useful.