# How to get the IP address used to connect to my server?

Tags: c, sockets, network-programming, ip-address

I have a server listening on multiple devices (LAN, WiFi and, possibly, some VPNs).

Listening binds a socket (AF_INET) binds INADDR_ANY to be exposed on all interfaces.

A client then connects and interchange starts.

At this point, how can I get information about which device was used for connection?

Equivalently: how can I get the IP address client used to connect?

**EDIT:**
Following @Barmar advice I tried the following:

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/ip.h>
#include <sys/un.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define handle_error(msg) \
        do { perror(msg); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); } while (0)

void error(char *msg)
{
    perror(msg);
    exit(1);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int sockfd, newsockfd, portno;
    unsigned clilen;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;
    struct sockaddr_in myaddr;
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sockfd < 0)
        error("ERROR creating socket");
    bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
    portno = 5666;
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
    if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
        error("ERROR on binding");
    listen(sockfd, 5);
    clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);
    newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &clilen);
    if (newsockfd < 0)
        error("ERROR on accept");

    clilen = sizeof(myaddr);
    if (getsockname(newsockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&myaddr, &clilen))
        error("ERROR in getsockname");

    unsigned int i = myaddr.sin_addr.s_addr;
    int p = myaddr.sin_port;
    int a = i & 0xff;
    i >>= 8;
    int b = i & 0xff;
    i >>= 8;
    int c = i & 0xff;
    i >>= 8;
    int d = i & 0xff;
    printf("my address is: %d.%d.%d.%d:%d\n", a, b,c, d, p);

    return 0;
}
```

... and (after a bit of debugging) it works.

Note that Port is not the value expected (5666) but consistently 8726.

Comment: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/accept.2.html `The argument addr is a pointer to a sockaddr structure.  This
       structure is filled in with the address of the peer socket`

Comment: I think he wants the local address that they connected to, not the address of the client.

Comment: I can confirm @Barmar interpretation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using a `SOCK_STREAM` socket (i.e. TCP), not `SOCK_DGRAM` (i.e. UDP), call [`getsockname()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getsockname.2.html) on the socket returned by `accept()`.

If you're using a datagram socket, I don't think there's a portable way to do it with a single socket. The traditional solution is to bind a separate socket for each local address, rather than using `INADDR_ANY`, and wait for a message on all of them using `epoll()` or `select()`. You can tell which address they connected to based on which socket the message was received on.

Linux and Windows have an extension that allows you to do this more easily, by setting the `IP_PKTINFO` option on the socket and using `recvmsg()` to receive a packet. In the `msgheader.msg_control` you can get the destination address of the packet. See [Get destination address of a received UDP packet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5281409/get-destination-address-of-a-received-udp-packet)

Comment: I tried to follow your advice, but I get always the INADDR_ANY (0.0.0.0) address (see my edit to the question).

Comment: You should be calling it on `newsockfd`, not `sockfd`.

Comment: Of course, my bad! Answer accepted. Can You explain why the Port No is always 8726 (instead of the expected 5666)? This happens also with `newsocket`.

Comment: You know how you have to call `htons()` when assigning to `sin_port`? You need to call `ntohs()` when reading it to reverse the process.

Comment: 5666 is 0x1622, 8726 is 0x2216 -- notice the relationship?

Comment: "*Linux has an extension that allows you to ... get the destination address of the packet*" - Windows has a [`WSARecvMsg()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741687(v=vs.85).aspx) function which supports a similar [`IP_PKTINFO` socket option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winsock/ip-pktinfo)

Comment: @RemyLebeau That requires using winsock, not regular sockets, right?

Comment: @Barmar They are the same thing. Winsock is the official socket library on Windows. It supports the usual BSD-style sockets that most platforms support, as well as its own WSA extensions.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I've updated the answer.